# Detect file changes in Visual Studio broken in my solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, orchardcms

I have an `Orchard CMS` source code solution as the basis for our application development. The problem we're facing is that `Visual Studio` does not reload file changes for files that reside [inside one of the projects] underneath the two solution folders `Modules` and `Themes`.

Note: the VS option `Detect when file is changed outside the environment` is checked.

It is noteworthy that all projects inside `Modules` and `Themes` physically reside underneath another project, the Orchard.Web project, in which these folders, `Modules` and `Themes`, are excluded from the project:

[image: Orchard project structure]

The problem with not reloading changed files does NOT occur for most other files in the solution (I haven't tried all of them ;-)), but specifically change detection works fine for files in other solution folders whose projects do NOT physically reside underneath another project, in this case `Orchard.Web`.

Trying a few things to fix the issue actually **solved it, but only on my machine** - on a coworker's it still does not work! These are the things I tried and which effect they had **on my machine**:

1. Deactivate all Visual Studio extensions -> no effect
2. Deleted the solution.suo file -> no effect
3. Unloaded all projects inside the `Modules` solution folder, unloaded the `Orchard.Web` project and reloaded them -> now change detection worked for those projects
4. Tried the same for projects inside the `Themes` folder -> no effect
5. Renamed `Themes` to `Themez` -> now change detection also worked for projects inside `Themez`
6. Renamed `Themez` back to `Themes` -> it still worked ...

**UPDATE:**
We set up a new solution without the `Orchard.Web` project and with that file change detection works as expected. Looks like there is a problem with that project setup.

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this problem on all machines working with this solution?

Comment: see UPDATE: new solution excluding the `Orchard.Web` project fixes the problem for now.

Comment: I deleted my `.suo` files and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including that folder (Themes.Discoverize) as part of the project? (Right click on files in directory "Include In Project")

Comment: The `Orchard.Web` project file should stay unchanged since it will be updated from source anytime a new version appears. Anyways, we tried your suggestion on my coworker's machine and unfortunately that didn't help either.